# Keras train_step() for contractive autoencoder (RuntimeError: Cannot get value inside Tensorflow graph function)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function, autoencoder

I've been trying to implement a Contractive Autoencoder. I'm using TF 2.10.1, and the custom **train_step()** generates a *RuntimeError: Cannot get value inside Tensorflow graph function*.

Can someone help me please? I follow a similar class implementation to Variational Autoencoder ([link](https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/)) from the Keras website as follows:

```
class CAE(tf.keras.Model):

# Constructor
def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, gamma, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.encoder = encoder
    self.decoder = decoder
    self.gamma = gamma
    self.total_loss_tracker = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='total_loss') # similarly for rec_loss_tracker, con_loss_tracker

# Metrics
@property
def metrics(self):
    return [self.total_loss_tracker, self.rec_loss_tracker, self.con_loss_tracker]

# Train step
def train_step(self, data):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        # forward prop
        z = self.encoder(data)
        reconstruction = self.decoder(z)

        # reconstruction loss
        rec_loss = loss_reconstruction(data, reconstruction)

        # contractive loss
        enc = self.encoder.get_layer('encoded')
        ws = tf.Variable(enc.get_weights()[0])  # RuntimeError
        ws = tf.transpose(ws)
        h = enc.output
        dh = h * (1 - h)
        con_loss = self.gamma * tf.reduce_sum(tf.linalg.matmul(dh ** 2, tf.square(ws)), axis=1)

        # total loss
        total_loss = rec_loss + con_loss

    grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_weights)
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))

    self.total_loss_tracker.update_state(total_loss)  # similarly for rec_loss_tracker, con_loss_tracker

    return {
        "total_loss": self.total_loss_tracker.result(),  # similarly for rec_loss_tracker, con_loss_tracker
    }
```